# Samba share not accessible to client in the same network

Tags: linux, windows, centos, samba, windows-server-2016

Two servers in the same network, a
Windows server (client), and a
Linux server (samba share host)

The shared folder can be seen by the client but not accessed. See below for the configuration:
smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user
        hosts allow = 192.168.1.40 #(windows server)
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        bind interfaces only = yes
        netbios name = test-server
        server role = standalone server
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m
        log level = 1


[testshare]
  path = /home/smbuser/testshare
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  guest only = yes
```

```
/home/smbuser/testshare:

drwxrwsrwx. 2 smbuser examplegroup   6 Sep  6 16:34 testshare
```

Firewalls are disabled on both sides.

Windows gives the error:

> Windows cannot access `\\192.168.1.20\testshare`

> You do not have permission to access `\\192.168.1.20\testshare`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two issues here

1. You're trying to access `\192.168.1.20\testshare` instead of `\\192.168.1.20\testshare`. I'm going to assume that's a typo but it's important to be precise
2. You have a `hosts allow = 192.168.1.20` entry in the `smb.conf`. The documentation (`man smb.conf`) describes this value as "*This parameter is a […] set of hosts which are permitted to access a service*". However, from your Windows client you're trying to access a server on address `192.168.1.20`, showing that your client can't be `192.168.1.20`. As a result any service will be refused.

   Temporarily, remove the `hosts allow` entry (comment it out) and test that you have connectivity. When you have confirmed this, put the line back but with the correct client IP address.

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for your reply,
I made alot of typos. the "host allow" IP was set correct but i changed it here out of habit. Anyway the shares can be seen by the windows server but not accessed, then i get the permission alert. but as far i can see it should be accessable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you give us incorrect information you will likely get incorrect answers

Comment: Have you looked at the SELinux tags for the part of the filesystem you want Samba to access, @Tango?

Comment: So i made a new folder on /mnt and edited the smb.conf and now i can access this new folder from the windows server but not write ;/

Comment: Directory permissions for `/mnt` please?

Comment: [root@tst-02 /]# ls -la | grep mnt
drwxrwxrwx.   5 root root    53 Sep 20 09:10 mnt

Comment: [root@tst-02 /]# ls -la /mnt

drwxrwxrwx.  4 smbuser smbuser   50 Sep 20 09:43 smbshare

Comment: Thank you Roaima, It was SElinux which was blocking me to write.